# How can two different creation stories be of two completely different religions yet be so similar

Tags: magic, culture, religion

The way magic works in my world is runes. Some runes especially the basic variety have a story behind them. The culture my story starts off in is matriarchy and has a reverence to the rune of warmth/fire they live in a particularly cold environment. The second story is  about a patriarchy society that lives in a blistering hot area they takes reverence to the rune of ice/cold. They both believe those runes were the first runes and built their religions based of those concepts. Their god/goddess is  ìṣúdudu the god of cold, family, and survival. Ashara the  goddess of warmth and love(romantic).

**ìṣúdudu creation of magic**- Drought plagued the land, In the desperate attempt to save his family  Alao left his village to save family. He faced many trials . Running across the Savannah, facing dangerous beast, and bearing the storm of sands. While on the journey he found his wife,who foolishly followed him she was to be taken by the heat. Alao begged someone, anyone to help her.  ìṣúdudu with all his power created the first rune to save his wife. A chill wrapped around them  almost freezing .  ìṣúdudu declared his creation to be Good.

**Ashara creation of magic***- A Frigid winter plagued the Land. In a foolhardy attempt to save his village a man left. A women of the named Commodia followed  him for he was her lover. The women faced many trials Frigid tall hill, dangerous Beast, and the storm of knives. She found her love,but he was to be taken by the ice.  She begged anyone to help him. Ashara with all her power created the first rune to save Lover.A warm almost burning heat wrapped around them. Ashara declared her creation to be Good.

Sorry for that wall of text. My Question is how can two different religions with very different philosophies, Gods/Goddesses and are on the opposite side  of the world from each other , Create such a similar story of magic?

Comment: We have different cultures who have the [same sort of stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flood_myths) in our world. Creation myths further sometimes seem very similar across rather different cultures. Folklore from different regions can talk about the same sort of creatures, too, like mermaids. All in all, despite vast distances we aren't THAT different. Some stories pass down from a common source and are adapted and further refined by cultures, other times people come up with similar ideas about the world indepenantly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Three Basic Theories

1. They're True. Magic came from the gods, and they either both are retelling the same event, but with a spin, or there were multiple instances of a god / gods bestowing magic onto the world and each religion focused on a different one.
2. Ideas spread between the religions. Maybe they both incorporated the same pre-existing fable into their teachings, or one borrowed from the other. Or maybe the religions share a common origin. One religion is a branch of the other, or they both are branches of an earlier religion.
3. Coincidence. An origin story about magic coming from the gods isn't too far-fetched, so it's entirely possible both came about independently in isolation.

It's also possible to use multiple. Different characters may have different opinions, well researched or not. A lack of consensus will likely seem more authentic than a single answer even if you as the author have a definitive one.

Comment: I like borrowed.  The older one has gravitas and rings true, and it is easiest to "use old code" - especially tested code.  The new religion had its own sociopolitical ends to achieve and so they tweaked the old one - old wine in new bottles as it were.   That has definitely happened with earthly religions.

Answer (score 1):

The basic elements from any foundation story come from the observation of the surrounding environment, and those are deeply rooted in the collective mind of the population of the planet.

I.e. water is essential to sustain life, thus life is born from water with the intervention of some god and the addition of some other ingredient for making i.e. mud.

You hardly find any real creation story which is based on fire.

The same can apply to your world.